# Using Omnifaces validateAllOrNone component into ui:repeat

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I have the following problem:

I try to use ***o:validateAllOrNone*** component into ui:repeat and it's work nice. But it doesn't work with my composite component.

My composite component it's really the simple ***p:inputText*** for comfortable input phone number. There I have used javascript which provides work with different phone numbers (inputPhoneNumber).

```
<p:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.id}" type="tel" label="Номер телефона" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
             styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass} m-pad-left50" style="#{cc.attrs.style}">
</p:inputText>

<script>
    $("#{cc.fullId}").intlTelInput(
        {
            utilsScript: "intl-tel-input/js/utils.js",
            autoHideDialCode: false,
            nationalMode: false,
            preferredCountries: [#{cc.preferredCountries}],
            onlyCountries: [#{cc.countries}],
            dropdownContainer: 'body'
        }
    );
</script>
```

Also I have the form to create contacts such as phone number, email, skype and et. The form allows to create list of contacts. And there I have used my composite component if category of contact is phone number else simple input text:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.contacts}" var="contact">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="contact_type" value="#{contact.type}">
       ...
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{contact.category.equals(category.PHONE)}">
        <mycomponent:inputPhoneNumber id="contact_phone_value" value="#{contact.value}" preferred="ru">
        <o:validateAllOrNone components="contact_type contact_phone_value"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ne contact.category.equals(category.PHONE)}">
        <p:inputText id="contact_other_value" value="#{contact.value}"/>
        <o:validateAllOrNone components="contact_type contact_other_value"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</ui:repeat>
```

I have used ***o:validateAllOrNone*** to check that contact type and his value not empty. It works for ***p:inputText*** but when I have tried to used this component for ***mycomponent:inputPhoneNumber*** I have caught the following exception:

> Exception message: ValidateAllOrNone attribute 'components' must refer
>   existing client IDs. Client ID 'contact_type' cannot be found.

I have found the question [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo) where I have known how to get full into ***ui:repeat***. After that I have rewritten my code:

```
<ui:repeat id="contact_list" value="#{bean.contacts}" var="contact" varStatus="status">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="contact_type" value="#{contact.type}">
       ...
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{contact.category.equals(category.PHONE)}">
        <mycomponent:inputPhoneNumber id="contact_phone_value" value="#{contact.value}" preferred="ru">
        <o:validateAllOrNone components="contact_creation_form-contact_list-#{status.index}-contact_type contact_phone_value"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ne contact.category.equals(category.PHONE)}">
        <p:inputText id="contact_other_value" value="#{contact.value}"/>
        <o:validateAllOrNone components="contact_type contact_other_value"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</ui:repeat>
```

Now I have put the correct id for contact type, but I caught the same exception:

> Exception message: ValidateAllOrNone attribute 'components' must refer
>   existing client IDs. Client ID
>   'contact_creation_form-list-2-contact_type' cannot be found.

How can I fix this proglem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should went from other side. It's easy to get the full id for the composite component and use it at ***o:validateAllOrNone***. It fixed the problem. The correct id for composite component in this case it is **contact_phone_value-contact_phone_value**. After that code lookes like:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.contacts}" var="contact">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="contact_type" value="#{contact.type}">
       ...
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{contact.category.equals(category.PHONE)}">
        <mycomponent:inputPhoneNumber id="contact_phone_value" value="#{contact.value}" preferred="ru">
        <o:validateAllOrNone components="contact_type contact_phone_value-contact_phone_value"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ne contact.category.equals(category.PHONE)}">
        <p:inputText id="contact_other_value" value="#{contact.value}"/>
        <o:validateAllOrNone components="contact_type contact_other_value"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</ui:repeat>
```

Also you should know that I use '-' instead ':' for id delimeter.